# Python3: Use Dateutil to make multiple vars from a long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dateutil

I have a program where I would like to randomly pull a line from a song, and string them together with other lines from other songs. Looking into I saw that the dateutil library might be able to help me parse multiple variables from a string, but it doesn't do quite what I want.

I have multiple strings like this, only much longer.

```
"This is the day\nOf the expanding man\nThat shape is my shade\nThere where I used to stand\nIt seems like only yesterday\nI gazed through the glass\n..."
```

I want to randomly pull one line from this string (To the page break) and save it as a variable but iterate this over multiple strings, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you want to pull a random line from a string of lines?

Comment: Is multiple variables at a time required or do you just need a random line from that concatenated string..?

Comment: What aspect of this problem are you asking about?  What, if any, aspects have you already addressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want to pull one line at random from the string you can use `choice` from the `random` module.

> **random. choice ( seq )**: Return a random element from the non-empty
>   sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

```py
from random import choice
data = "This is the day\nOf the expanding man\nThat shape is my shade\nThere where I used to stand\nIt seems like only yesterday\nI gazed through the glass\n..."
my_lines = data.splitlines()
my_line = choice(my_lines)
print(my_line)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
That shape is my shade
```